# Invalid syntax error when applying lambda for multiple columns processing

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following code that should put either 0 or 1 into the column `INDICATOR` depending on if-then rules (values of columns `T` and `S`):

```
rawdata_base['INDICATOR'] = rawdata_base.apply(lambda row: 
                                   '1' if row['T']=='2' and str(row['S']).isdigit() and int(row['S'])<15 
                                   else '0' if row['T']=='2' and str(row['S']).isdigit() and int(row['S'])>=15
                                   else '1' if row['T']=='1' and str(row['S']).isdigit() and int(row['S'])<35 
                                   else '0' if row['T']=='1' and str(row['S']).isdigit() and int(row['S'])>=35
                                   else '0' if 'A' in row['S']
                                   else '0', axis 1)
```

I cannot figure out why the error `invalid syntax` pops up at the line `else '0', axis 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can't stack conditionals like that in python. Ternary conditional operators can only take 3 inputs (hence ternary): `a if b else c`.

If you want to stack them, then I don't think you want a `lambda` here. Make your own function:

```
def myfunc(row):
    if row['T']=='2' and str(row['S']).isdigit() and int(row['S'])<15:
        return '1'
    elif row['T']=='2' and str(row['S']).isdigit() and int(row['S'])>=15:
        return '0'
    ...
```

Then in your `.apply` function, pass `myfunc`

Comment: Doe you mean `rawdata_base.apply(processRow(row), axis=1)`? Should I use `lambda row: processRow(row), axis=1`?

Comment: If i run `rawdata_base.apply(lambda x: processRow(row), axis=1)`, it gives me the error `TypeError: ("argument of type 'float' is not iterable", u'occurred at index 2408')`. But I do not see any fload at row 2408.

Comment: Try `rawdata_base.apply(processRow, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing '='. It should be 'axis=1' not 'axis 1'

Answer (score 0):

As @gipsy mentioned, one of the errors was the lack of `=` (`axis=1`). However, the main error was to miss `str` in this line of code `elif 'A' in str(row['S']):`